# App Store: Can I limit downloads of my app to camera-only devices?

Tags: iphone, camera, app-store

I've written an app that requires a camera to work (there's not really any point in the app without a camera being present).

I'm currently doing all the last little bits required for submission to the app store. Should there be an option anywhere or a .plist property I can set so that non-camera devices won't be able to download my app? Or, should I just make it clear in the description?

Any help is much appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Look at the info.plist 'Required device capabilities' setting.

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/BuildTimeConfiguration/BuildTimeConfiguration.html

(Search that URL for 'required device capabilities').

Comment: Thanks! Searched round for this but missed it - was staring at me all along :)

Answer (score 2):

You should also make it clear in your description, as well as the plist.  People with multiple previous devices might be able to download your app using iTunes on their Mac or PC, even if they do not currently have a device with a camera.

Comment: Agreed, that sounds like the way to go.